# pyspark can't stop reading empty string as null (spark 3.0)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

I have a some csv data file like this (^ as delmiter):

| ID | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  |  |
| 1 | Mike | 20 |

When I do

```
df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "^").option("quote","").option("header", "true").option(
        "inferSchema", "true").csv(xxxxxxx)
```

spark will default the 2 column after 0 row to null

```
df.show():
```

| ID | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | null | null |
| 1 | Mike | 20 |

How can I stop pyspark to read the data as null but just empty string?

I have tried add some option in the end

```
1,option("nullValue", "xxxx").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", False)
2,option("nullValue", None).option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", False)
3,option("nullValue", None).option("emptyValue", None)
4,option("nullValue", "xxx").option("emptyValue", "xxx")
```

But no matter what I do pyspark is still reading the data as null.. Is there a way to make pyspark read the empty string as it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that the empty values since `Spark Version 2.0.1` are treated as null. A manner to achieve your result is using `df.na.fill(...)`:

```py
df = spark.read.csv('your_data_path', sep='^', header=True)
# root
#  |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- age: string (nullable = true)

# Fill all columns
# df = df.na.fill('')

# Fill specific columns
df = df.na.fill('', subset=['name', 'age'])

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output

```
+---+----+---+
|ID |name|age|
+---+----+---+
|0  |    |   |
|1  |Mike|20 |
+---+----+---+
```